# Uniform distribution of survivor evaluated at lifetime

Tags: probability-distributions

The question is:

> Let $T$ be a continuous random variable with survivor function $S$ defined on the interval $[0, \omega]$.
>
> Now consider the random variable $S(T)$, the survivor function evaluated at the unknown lifetime value $T$.
>
> Show that $S(T)$ has a Uniform$[0,1]$ distribution.

My attempt at answering it is:

$P(S(T) \leq x) = P(T \leq S^{-1}(x))$

Where $S^{-1}(x) = \inf\left\lbrace t : S(t) \leq x \right\rbrace$

So then

$P(T \leq S^{-1}(x)) = 1 - P(T > S^{-1}(x)) = 1 -S(S^{-1}(x)) = 1 - x$

But the cdf of a Uniform$[0,1]$ distribution should be $x$ not $1-x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the survival function is one minus the cumulative distribution function, so you have

$$S(x) = 1-P(T\leq x) = P(T> x)$$

Also, since it is non-increasing, you need to reverse inequality signs when you apply its inverse to both sides of an inequality. Hence (modulo equality)

$$
\begin{align}
P(S(T)\leq x) & = P(T\geq S^{-1}(x)) \\
& = S(S^{-1}(x)) \\
& = x
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thanks, out of interest, could you explain where my attempt went wrong?

Comment: I edited to explain it a bit better - essentially, when you apply $S^{-1}$ to both sides of the inequality, you need to reverse the direction of the inequality, because $S$ is decreasing.

Comment: Ah I see now, thanks again.